# perforce: is there a way to force revert all opened files from ALL sites?

Tags: perforce, revert

Sorry i just updated my question.

Actually I'm working with 2 sites.

I have admin rights to the perforce server.
We are trying to design something that can integrate into a branch forcefully.
so we would like to make sure the destination branch does not have any opened files, by anyone, from any workspace, from any sites.

Is there a way for me to achieve that?

something like this?

```
p4 revert <some option> //depot/destination/branch/...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What situation are you trying to avoid by making sure nobody has opened files?

Comment: Does reverting everybody's files actually solve your problem?  Is that not racy?  Wouldn't locking the files be more appropriate?

Comment: @Samwise when i try to integrate to a branch, and that branch happens to have an exclusive(text+l) file that is opened, the `p4 integrate` command fails. My ultimate goal is to make sure that the integrate command works.

Comment: That makes sense -- but make sure to limit this to *only* `+l` files that are touched by the integrate then.  (Also, consider limiting usage of `+l` files if their semantics are causing more headaches than they're preventing.)  You should also not use `integrate -f` since that will force all files to be touched; use `p4 copy` if your intent is to make the target branch identical (it'll skip already-identical files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an admin it's possibly to forcefully revert files from the server side (i.e. make the server treat them as no longer open) with the `-C` flag (you may also need `--remote` in a DVCS configuration):

```
%p4 help revert

    revert -- Discard changes from an opened file

        ...

        The -C flag allows a user to specify the workspace that has the file
        opened rather than defaulting to the current client workspace. When
        this option is used, the '-k' flag is also enabled and the check for
        matching user is disabled. The -C flag requires 'admin' access, which
        is granted by 'p4 protect'.

        The --remote flag is useful for DVCS configurations in which files
        of type +l are in use. 'p4 revert --remote=origin filename' reverts
        the named file in your DVCS server, and additionally, if the file is
        of type +l, releases the global exclusive lock on the file in the
        origin server.
```

This does *not* actually modify the files in the affected workspaces; those workspaces will therefore be in an inconsistent state, and may be at risk of losing changes if the user is not careful (i.e. their work in progress may be overwritten by a sync operation and/or missed by a submit).

I would recommend *only* doing the force revert if the files are locked; files that are opened but unlocked will not interfere with the integration, and reverting them will only make it more difficult for those users to reconcile their workspaces after the fact.